# How long does OnStar RemoteLink app take to refresh from a Chevy Volt?

Tags: chevrolet

It takes anywhere from 20 to 60 seconds to get the status from my car (like if I want to know how charged the battery is).

I'm wondering if this is normal or something is wrong.

Comment: Yes something is wrong, but with OnStar not your app!  I believe it bounces the signal off the sun for some reason--still investigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is normal. Not to get into details but there is no direct link between your OnStar RemoteLink app and your car. Here is how it works:

1. Your applications calls a server at GM and places a request ( for example check battery status ).
2. The server makes a series of queries in order to make to establish connection with a car. It could be sending sms or other ways ( there are two other way - if I remember correctly, just can't recall right now).
3. Once connection is established between a car and a GM server, it will execute desired command - check battery status as well as receive few more pieces of info.
4. And at last, a GM server will return requested information to your app.

Now to the best of my knowledge, it takes a bit of time to do step 2 because it is a bit tricky to establish connection with a car that is not working. Remember your car doesn't stay connected to OnStar server all the time because it will drain battery and it will cost GM a bit of money to keep connection alive - GM uses cellular providers (AT&T and such) and they charge an arm & a leg for internet connection such as 3G and LTE.

In any case, 20-60 seconds to get an update from a car is normal.